# textbox value not being grabbed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form that is not behaving how I would expect and I am a bit stumped.  On the form, a phone number populates from the database to a textbox.  This part is working fine.  The user then has the option to edit the value in the textbox, and press a button that updates the value in the database with the value in the textbox. This is the part that is not working.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class contact_edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //sql connection here

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string phoneNum = "";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("getContactInfo", cn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            phoneNum = myReader.GetString(3).ToString();
        }

        cn.Close();

        //If I take this part out and don't populate textbox,
        //my update works.  If I leave it, it does not
        phone.Text = phoneNum.ToString();

    }
    protected void update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn.Open();

        phone.Text = "";

        string updatedPhone = phone.Text;

        string updateSQLString = "update contact set Phone_num = '" + updatedPhone +   
        "'";

        SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSQLString, cn);
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("contact_edit.aspx");
}
```

}

When I hit the button to call my update method.  It attempts to get the value of the phone  textbox.  But after the form loads, and I change the textbox value and then hits the update button, it keeps getting the value that was originally assigned to the textbox when the form loads. Why is this happening?

Comment: postbacks postbacks postbacks!

Comment: you should really refactor the code especially the section on Page_Load where you are doing database calls. this should be in a separate method in my opinion because of the `PostBack` you are not doing any code that indicates `If(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Could be due to page postback. consider reading this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68371/Detecting-Refresh-or-Postback-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because you are loading the value from database on every postback. Wrap it in a `IsPostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // only load the value on the first load
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` around your page_load code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        string phoneNum = "";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("getContactInfo", cn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            phoneNum = myReader.GetString(3).ToString();
        }

        cn.Close();

        //If I take this part out and don't populate textbox,
        //my update works.  If I leave it, it does not
        phone.Text = phoneNum.ToString();
     }

    }
```

Comment: What if the database schema changes.. this line here `phoneNum = myReader.GetString(3).ToString();` would fail why are you not grabbing the field by it's Name vs Indexed position..?

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was missing

Comment: DJ KRAZE, this is also a good point.  I don't see the schema changing, but you never know.  And that would save me a lot of headeache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     //access data here
     //assign value here
     phone.Text = phoneNum.ToString();  
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was missing